# How does Excel determine default cell formula when a new line is added to a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

It appears as though a certain column in my table has established a default formula that I can't seem to reset. When I add a new row to the table, the cell in that column always puts this default formula. How do I change this default?

Similar to other questions: [Excel table inserting old formula in new rows. How can I reset to the new formula?](https://superuser.com/questions/1229050/excel-table-inserting-old-formula-in-new-rows-how-can-i-reset-to-the-new-formul)
[Excel: set default formula for each cell in column](https://superuser.com/questions/1302185/excel-set-default-formula-for-each-cell-in-column)
[How to change underlying formula for Excel Table?](https://superuser.com/questions/932696/how-to-change-underlying-formula-for-excel-table)

Answer (score 0):

When you change the formula in that cell, you will get an auto-correct prompt that will let you choose to update the Calculated Column formula.

Comment: I do not want to reset it to the calculated column formula, I want to remove the column formula (and understand why it gets set). Thanks!

Comment: quickest way to remove the formula is to convert to a range, then convert back to table

Comment: That's what I've read - shoot, I was hoping there was some way to avoid that :D

Comment: You can also decompress the excel file and remove it there but it's hardly easier